# Error running GMM - system is computationally singular

Tags: r, gmm

I need help, I try to run a GMM estimation method in R but it gives me the error message,

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(WX, t(crossprod(WX, A2)))) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.59161e-23
```

Which I don't understand.

I'm using a dynamic panel model (Consumption is the dependent variable and lag consumption is also included as an independent variable.
to study the effect of GDP on consumption.

Comment: It means that you have at least two variables that perfectly correlate with one another. if you are doing one-hot encoding, you need to remove a variable, which will be the reference variable.

Comment: In the very unlikely scenario that multicollinearity isn't the issue, you can change the tolerance, as well. The current tolerance is attainable by entering `.Machine$double.eps` into the console.

Comment: But  it only gives results when I used Individual effect and not with two ways effect.  What could be the possible interpretation?